# margin-top not working properly inside inline-block form

Tags: css, html

I have a form that has a input text type inside, I am placing it right in front of a select object with the following code, but it is not exactly aligned with the select object.

[image]

When I try to introduce margin-top in the css as shown below, it moves both the select object and the text box below:

```
form {
    display: inline-block;
}

.textBox
{
margin-top:50px;
}
```

Please guide me about this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the margin for `.textBox` and try this:

```
form{display:block;}    
form input{
    display: inline-block; vertical-align:middle;
}
```

WARNING: this will align ALL your input elements, so you may need to add more declarations if you have more elements and you need it so. If it's just these 2 elements, then you'll be OK

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `margin-top:.5em;` in the style of the line:

```
 <input class="textBox" type="text" value="A random value" style="width:222px;     height:36px; font-size:24px; padding-left:11px;padding-top:2px;color:#666666; margin-top:.5em;">
```

Comment: It is still moving both the objects together, both select item and the text input move together, please also see the image I have added to the question, that may give you a better idea of the issue